# Is it possible to set a speicifc byte in a RandomAccessFile back to null?

Tags: java, random-access

Origianlly, when I created the RandomAccessFile, I skipped over some bytes so those stayed as null, but now I need to delete some of the bytes I wrote. Right now, what I'm doing is overwriting the location with a space, but is there a way to set it back to empty?

EDIT: Since It has to contain a value, I would like to know how to set it back to the original value that it is assigned by default when it is skipped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A file cannot contain an "empty" byte. Each byte in the file must have a value between 0 and 255.

If you want to "erase" all bytes after a certain point, you could use `RandomAccessFile.setLength` which truncates the file.

---

Regarding your comment: If you want to set some bytes back to it's original value, I suggest you encapsulate a `RandomAccessFile` in your own class with a map from index to original byte value, which you update in each call to `write`. This subclass could then provide a method `restore(int i)` that restores the value of the byte at index `i` by looking up the original value in the map.

Comment: I guess I mean set it back to what it was originally

Comment: @chustar: Then you'd need to know what it was originally.

Comment: No, there is no "undo" history in a `RandomAccessFile`.

Answer (score 1):

It's extremely unclear what you're trying to do, but you can't "delete" bytes from the start or middle of a file. You can generally *truncate* a file, but you can't remove bits from the middle - you'd normally create a new file, only copying the data you want, and then possibly rename the files appropriately.

Comment: I finally understood what I was doing. I was looking for a way to write the "null" character `\0` on the spots I wanted to "delete".   I didn't know if there was a name for this sort of operation.

Comment: @chustar: Yes, it's just writing data as normal... where your data happens to be 0 bytes. (Not characters, by the way... it's worth distinguishing between text and binary data. RandomAccessFile itself deals with binary data.)